# Running Count within groups in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an Orders database for an online shopping platform.

The table I'm working with looks like this, where each line corresponds to one customer/item/date.

```
OrderHistory <- data.frame(date=c("2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-05-01"), 
            customer=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
            item=c("Candy", "Coffee", "Coffee", "Candy", "Candy", "Candy", "Coffee" ))
```

What I would like to get is  a running count of the number of times each member has ordered the specific item so I can run analysis on which items are ordered repeatedly by the same customers and which ones are ordered once and never again.

The output would look like

```
out <- data.frame(date=c("2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-05-01"), 
              member=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
              item=c("Candy", "Coffee", "Coffee", "Candy", "Candy", "Candy", "Coffee" ),
              count=c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1))
```

I would love a dplyr solution but I'm open to any suggestions! The exact items on the platform are constantly changing, so the solution would have to be dynamic to account for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you want

```
library(dplyr)
OrderHistory %>%
    group_by(customer, item) %>%
    mutate(count = seq(n()))

Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: customer, item

        date customer   item count
1 2015-02-01        A  Candy     1
2 2015-03-01        A Coffee     1
3 2015-04-01        A Coffee     2
4 2015-03-01        B  Candy     1
5 2015-04-01        B  Candy     2
6 2015-05-01        B  Candy     3
7 2015-05-01        B Coffee     1
```

Comment: Amazing. Such an elegantly simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten your "dplyr" answer, but a straightforward way in base R is to use `ave`:

```
ave(rep(1, nrow(OrderHistory)), OrderHistory[-1], FUN = seq_along)
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1
```

---

You can also use `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(OrderHistory, c("customer", "item"))
#          date customer   item .id
# 1: 2015-02-01        A  Candy   1
# 2: 2015-03-01        A Coffee   1
# 3: 2015-04-01        A Coffee   2
# 4: 2015-03-01        B  Candy   1
# 5: 2015-04-01        B  Candy   2
# 6: 2015-05-01        B  Candy   3
# 7: 2015-05-01        B Coffee   1
```